# MongoDB find the corrupted doc

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of 9 million records where I found an index in which if I tried to get all the documents, it throws the below error.

```
Error: error: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "invalid bson type in element with field name '_contract_end_date' in object with unknown _id",
"code" : 22,
"codeName" : "InvalidBSON",
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1585753324, 14),
"$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1585753324, 14),
    "signature" : {
        "hash" : BinData(0,"2fEF+tGQoHsjvCCWph9YhkVajCs="),
        "keyId" : NumberLong("6756221167083716618")
    }
}
```

}

So I tried to rename the field to `contract_end_date` by using `$rename` operator. When I tried `updateMany`, it throws the same error.

But `updateOne` works. But this is not helpful as I just see the success message but not actually updating 100 odd docs for that index. I wonder how to see that corrupted doc to identify the other fields which will help me to identify the application which corrupts.

Sample doc: -It's a pretty simple flatten structure - around 50 fields are there in each doc - no nested docs.

```
{
 _id:
 sys_contract_end_date:
 customer_name:
 location:
 owner:
 retailer:
 seller:
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your docs

Comment: @whoami Please check my edit

Comment: What if you try to find it this way, let's say you've a field type boolean & for one doc it's inserted as string, you can get that doc with string by this `db.collection.find({$expr: {$ne: [{$type: "$abc"},"bool"]}})` ,**Test :** (https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y3xt_lC3G9A)